# How can I append another dataframe to a dataframe of the same structure and eliminate duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with words, an id and a code for the language. I have run this dataframe through a spellchecking algorithm - which returned a dataframe with only the words that needed a correction - and now I need to add the corrected words back to the original dataframe but this time the corrected word should replace the wrong one (I'm guessing I need to specify this with the id somehow).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I have just appended the new dataframe back to the original for now and there's a number at the end for some reason...

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15239951)

Answer (score 0):

Without sample, it's hard to answer.

```
pd.concat([original_df, fixed_df]).drop_duplicates(['id', 'code'], keep='last')
```

```
>>> df1
   words  id code
0   helo   1    A
1  world   2    B

>>> df2
   words  id code
0  hello   1    A

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(['id', 'code'], keep='last')
   words  id code
1   word   2    B
0  hello   1    A
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but for some reason it does the same thing as when I use append. I also get this error message 'sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.'

Comment: What is the output of `df1.info()` and `df2.info()`?

Comment: df1 if <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 227656 entries, 0 to 227655
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------    --------------   ----- 
 0   id        227656 non-null  object
 1   name      227653 non-null  object
 2   language  227654 non-null  object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 5.2+ MB

Comment: df2 is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 58369 entries, 0 to 58368
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   Unnamed: 0  58369 non-null  int64 
 1   id          58369 non-null  int64 
 2   name        58366 non-null  object
 3   language    58369 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 1.8+ MB

Comment: Can you try that: `pd.concat([df1, df2[df1.columns].astype({'id': str})])`

Comment: Ok this seems to solve the problem of the extra column (Unnamed: 0) at the end and there's no number anymore but then when I use this line and the drop_duplicates as well but the drop duplicates does not seem to work

Comment: Also as soon as I try the drop_duplicates on the new df I get the same last Unnamed column and the duplicates are still there

Comment: Try to write your dataframes to csv file and reload it. `df1.to_csv("df1.csv", index=False)` and `df2[df1.columns].to_csv("df2.csv", index=False)` then `pd.concat([pd.read_csv("df1.csv"), pd.read_csv("df2.csv")]).drop_duplicates(['id', 'code'], keep='last')`

Comment: you mean df1 = df1.to_csv("df1.csv", index=False), df2 = df2[df1.columns].to_csv("df2.csv", index=False) and then pd.concat([pd.read_csv("df1.csv") and pd.read_csv("df2.csv")]).drop_duplicates(['id', 'code'], keep='last') ?

Comment: I keep getting this error NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: I also tried solving this with for loops but it is a nighmare runtime wise... It won't finish running in 20 mins -which is long even for those 200k long Dataframes I think

Comment: if you want to share your 2 csv files, I can take a look.